# Rails 4: Sorting by 2 different scopes/class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to sort my events by future events *then* by events that have already ended. I tried using 2 different scopes but I'm thinking now that I might need to use class methods instead. I'm just struggling on how, syntactically, I need to write these methods.

**event.rb**:

```
def active
 self.event_date > Time.now
end

def inactive
 self.event_date < Time.now
end
```

"event_date" is a datetime column in the events table.

**events_controller.rb**:

```
def index
 @events = Event.all.sort_by {|a,b| [a.active, b.inactive]}
end
```

With this code, I'm getting an error: "undefined method `inactive' for nil:NilClass" but I've tried it several different ways and can't seem to figure out how to write it.

Comment: Why not just order by event_date?

Comment: @ReubenMallaby because I'd like to order by the active events in ascending order followed by the inactive events.

Comment: `sort_by` uses only one argument for its block: `Event.all.sort_by{ |event| event.active }` (which can be simplified to `Event.all.sort_by(&:active)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods will be executed after running through the database and will be slow.

This can probably be improved:

Model

```
scope :active, -> { where('event_date >= ?', Time.now) }
scope :inactive, -> { where('event_date < ?', Time.now) }
```

Controller

```
@active_events = Event.active
@inactive_events = Event.inactive

@events = @active_events + @inactive_events
```

Comment: This did the trick with the addition of the "?" by @ilya. Thank you.

Comment: Well spotted @ilya!